# Не работает on_member_join discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

В моем боте я хочу сделать приветствие пришедших на сервер пользователей, попробовал через on_member_join, но не вышло, участники заходят а бот не отвечает.
Я знаю, такие вопросы уже были заданы на StackOverflow, но ответы на них не помогли мне.
В настройках бота на сайте Discord у меня включены пункты Presence Intent и Server Members Intent, но и с ними `intents = discord.Intents.all()` не работает.
Вот код:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$", intents = discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Человек зашел на сервер")
```

В чем здесь моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Код работает, значит проблема в чем-то другом.

В настройках, на вкладке `Конфиденциальность` есть вот такой пункт. Проверьте, включен ли он у вас

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]